# how to print a value from textbox

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function submit()
{
var name = document.getElementById("name");
document.getElementById("resltado").innerHTML = name.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Yourname" name="name"  size="20" id="name" required value="" />
<input type="button" value="SUBMIT" id="submit" onclick="javascript:submit();" />
<p id="resultado"></p>
```

This code is not working,and text box value not print,so please give me some ideas to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set the value to an element which does not exist. 
`document.getElementById("resltado")` will return you `null` because there is no HTML element with id `resltado`. You do have an element with id `resultado`. So it seems you misspelled it in the JS code.

```js
function submit()
{
var name = document.getElementById("name");
document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = name.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Yourname" name="name"  size="20" id="name" required value="" />
<input type="button" value="SUBMIT" id="submit" onclick="javascript:submit();" />
<p id="resultado"></p>
```

Comment: It looks like it's a misspelling of the `resultado` paragraph element.

Comment: Questions where the problem is caused by a typo are not useful in the long term. You should point out the type in a comment and vote to close the question instead of answering it.

Comment: @Quentin I gave him a pass on this - he didn't realize it was a typo until after he'd answered the question differently and it was subsequently pointed out.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy — There's a delete link that an author can use to delete an answer.